# Getting syntaxError unexpected token illegal while converting string to object

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, type-conversion

I am trying to convert the provided string in array of objects

```
var string = "[{cpu:100,memory:47,freeDisk:83,networks:[{name: \"ctm-4680b9b244c\", status : \"active\"},{name: \"ctm-c2f21106323\", status : \"active\"},{name: \"ctz-1977174d443\", status : \"active\"},{name: \"ctz-1b49d8ccfa5\", status : \"active\"},{name: \"ctz-28c7ceda9ce\", status : \"active\"},{name: \"ctz-3337b7f252a\", status : \"active\"},{name: \"ctz-bbe9792d0c7\", status : \"active\"},{name: \"ctz-d400e32307d\", status : \"active\"},{name: \"ens33\", status : \"active\"},{name: \"lo\", status : \"active\"},{name: \"ctz-9bf91c248f9\", status : \"inactive\"}],infrastructurename:\"ct-colormaster-host\", infrastructurestatus:\"running\", infrastructureuptime: \"Sat Aug 12 00:00:00 UTC 2017\", infrastructureuptimeSince:{ days: 0, hours: 3, minutes: 39},infrastructuredowntime:', infrastructuredowntimeSince:{days: 0, hours: 0, minutes: 0}, infrastructurecurrentCheckTime : \"Sat Aug 12 06:23:25 UTC 2017\"}]"
```

I need to convert it into

```
[
  { 
    cpu:100,
    memory: 47,
    freeDisk: 83,
    networks: [
      {
        name: "ctm-4680b9b244c",
        status: "active"
      },
      {
        name: "ctm-c2f21106323",
        status: "active"
      },
      ... 
    ]
  }
]
```

I tries `JSON.parse` and `eval` but both of them are not working and giving me **unexpected token illegal error**.

Please suggest me how to convert this string into object.

Comment: Why is it a string in the first place? Just declare it with a JavaScript object literal.

Comment: I don't know but getting this string from elastic search

Comment: The contents of the string are valid JavaScript syntax, but not valid JSON syntax.

Comment: @frank, either ways are fine `cpu` or `"cpu"`

Comment: Not in JSON. In JSON notation, property names **must** be quoted with double-quote characters.

Comment: Don't mess with this in JavaScript. Get your elastic search to output valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If it has to be a string first, you need quotes around the property names:

```
[{ "cpu" : 100 }]
```

Also, I'm not sure if you are creating the string inline just for the question or if you are doing that in your actual code. If it's in your actual code, you could use single quotes to avoid escaping double quotes:

```
var string = '[{"name": "ctm-4680b9b244c"}]'
```

Comment: Single-quotes would still be a problem if any embedded string value contained a single-quote. It'd be better to use *no outer quotes at all*.